# On Heroku, is it safe to run Gunicorn out in front?

Tags: python, security, heroku, webserver, gunicorn

Nearly every description I've read about deploying Python on Heroku is essentially:

1. Add `gunicorn` to `requirements.txt
2. Add `web: gunicorn wsgi:application` to `Procfile`
3. Profit

The [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn) are essentially the same as well.

However, the [Gunicorn docs](http://gunicorn.org/index.html#deployment) make it pretty clear that it "is best to use Gunicorn behind HTTP proxy server", and it specifically recommends Nginx. Heroku doesn't mention this, and nobody else does. In fact, everybody I know that runs Gunicorn on Heroku runs it as a standalone server. With [WhiteNoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/latest/django.html#enable-whitenoise) you can even serve your static files fairly efficiently, so that's not a big concern, until the traffic and costs grow beyond what's acceptable.

Is it that Heroku's HTTP routing is handling a lot of the cases that Gunicorn doesn't (slowloris attacks, etc.), which makes it safe, or are all of these folks (including Heroku) simply taking a technical low road, because it's easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku [is the proxy server](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-faq#do-python-applications-run-behind-nginx) in this instance.

Comment: Heroku acts as a proxy server, but not a *buffering* proxy server which is what gunicorn requires.

Comment: I've added a link to https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-faq#do-python-applications-run-behind-nginx and selected your answer as the correct one, since that is official Heroku documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You're right: the people recommending gunicorn are taking a technical low road because it's easier.

Heroku does provide [some buffering](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#request-buffering), but it's insufficient to protect against slowloris-type attacks.

There's a nice blog post here which explains in more detail:
http://blog.etianen.com/blog/2014/01/19/gunicorn-heroku-django/

The solution recommended there is to use [Waitress](https://pylons.readthedocs.org/projects/waitress/en/latest/), which is pure-Python webserver which handles buffering correctly.

Comment: Another solution is to use the nginx buildpack https://simonwillison.net/2017/Oct/2/nginx-heroku/